# On iOS, is there a quicker way to get the URL of the mainBundle resource?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, foundation

It seems a bit strange that we have to use such a long way to get to a file's path:

```
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                            pathForResource:@"0" ofType:@"aiff"]];
```

I wonder is there a faster way, such as a class method for `NSURL` or `NSBundle`?

```
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL urlFromMainBundle:@"0.aiff"];
```

or

```
NSURL *soundURL = [NSBundle urlFromMainBundle:@"0.aiff"];
```

If not, is there a reason why it is not a good form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"0" withExtension:@"aiff"];
```

Starting from there, you could also write a category for `NSURL` or `NSBundle`:

```
@interface NSURL (NSURL+Resource)
+ (NSURL *)URLForResource:(NSString *)resource;
@end

@implementation NSURL (NSURL+Resource)

+ (NSURL *)URLForResource:(NSString *)resource
{
   NSString *name = [resource stringByDeletingPathExtension];
   NSString *extension = [resource pathExtension];

   return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:name withExtension:extension];
}

@end
```

Comment: That's nice, thanks.  And how can you add that class method to `NSURL`? (add to a framework's `.h` and `.m` file?  What if later on we compile our projects on a different Mac with its own installation of Xcode?

Comment: Uhm, no, you create a category on `NSURL`. Don't mess with the frameworks files (besides that there aren't any `.m` files and the `.h` files are read only). See my edit on how to write it as an category.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`URLForResource:withExtension:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource%3awithExtension%3a) in the `NSBundle` class:

```
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"0" withExtension:@"aiff"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"0" withExtension:@"aiff"];
```